# Assigning filtered DataGridView to DataRow[] giving null value (filter has result)

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, nullreferenceexception

I am working on a Windows Form Application with C#.

I have a form with `DataGridView` which you can add/delete entry, entry has editable `Qty` column, then a `Save` Button.

Upon clicking `Save`, I want to filter the `DataGridView` entries for `0.00 Qty`, then notify the user that there is/are a `0.00 Qty` on the list, else will proceed the saving. (see screenshot of the form before clicking Save)

[image: Form where the user add/delete entry and set the Qty]

I have this below code on the form:

```
    private void SaveBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (isWithZeroQty() == true)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please check Quantity","System Alert",MessageBoxButtons.OK,MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
        }
        else
        {
            // Will do the saving..
        }
    }

    private bool isWithZeroQty()
    {
        DataRow[] result = (enrollmedsDataGridView.DataSource as DataTable).Select("Qty = 0.00 OR Qty = 0");

        if (result.Count() > 0)
        { return true; }
        else
        { return false; }
    }
```

My problem is a `NullReferenceException` occurred in this line:

```
DataRow[] result = (enrollmedsDataGridView.DataSource as DataTable).Select("Qty = 0.00 OR Qty = 0");
```

Upon my further investigation, NullReferenceException occurs on casting of DataGridView as DataTable `(enrollmedsDataGridView.DataSource as DataTable)`.

Is it because the DataGridView is DataBounded to BindingSource?

If so, how can i workaround with this.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still can't find the reason why NullReferenceException occurs on the code above.

But as a workaround, instead of Filtering and Casting `DataGridView` to `DataTable` I used foreach on every row to check the cell `Qty` if it has `0 or 0.00` values which works fine on my end.

See below code:

```
    private bool isWithZeroQty()
    {
        int zeros = 0;
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in enrollmedsDataGridView.Rows)
        {
            if ((row.Cells["Qty"].Value.ToString() == "0") || (row.Cells["Qty"].Value.ToString() == "0.00"))
            {
                zeros = 1;
            }
        }
        if (zeros > 0)
        { return true; }
        else
        { return false; }
    }
```